# PCA on features vector for image point recognition

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-recognition, sift, nearest-neighbor

I am matching points between two images. I am picking the interest points through harris corner detector, using a sift feature for the features of these interest points, and am then matching these features through the nearest neighbors ratio. All of this is being done in Matlab. The features vector is very large and I want to reduce the dimension but still preserve the features so that I can match them. I want to do PCA on this features vector. Does anyone know of any Matlab approaches to do this while preserving accuracy from the original vector?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have your whole cake and eat it too. :)

Applying dimensionality reduction provides a smaller dataset (since the number of dimensions is decreased), thus faster execution, but you have to give up on some accuracy.

And that comes naturally, I mean less information, less accuracy, but faster process.

If I were you I would reduce my features from 128 dimensions you now have, since you use SIFT features to 64 dimensions and run my algorithm with both the 64-dim features and with the 128-dim features, and compare accuracy and speed, to see what's optimal.

Of course, you could use [Matlab's PCA](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pca.html).